# Gráfico de barras duplas

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de barras duplas com o seguinte data frame:

```
Total_CPIs <- data.frame(Período =c(1995, 1999, 2003, 2007, 2011), 
                SP = c(12, 11, 2, 20, 22), RS = c(3, 4, 2, 4, 4))
```

A coluna `Período` refere-se ao ano de início de cada Legislatura; `SP` são as CPIs ocorridas em São Paulo e; `RS` as CPIs ocorridas no Rio Grande do Sul.

A ideia é que no final eu tenha por Legislatura as barras com as CPIs em cada Estado e gostaria de colocar em cima das barras a quantidade total (número) de CPIs. Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como começar esse gráfico?

Answer (score 3):

O melhor para fazer o que a pergunta pede é usar o pacote `ggplot2`.
Vou ainda usar o pacote `reshape2` para reformatar os dados de formato largo para formato longo.

```
library(ggplot2)

longo <- reshape2::melt(Total_CPIs, id.vars = "Período")

ggplot(longo, aes(x = factor(Período), y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(1), stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = value, label = value), vjust = -0.2,
            position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  xlab("Período")  +
  ylab("CPIs")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Notei que você fez uma nova pergunta querendo saber como trabalhar com a legenda do gráfico.

A minha sugestão é parecida com a do colega, com algumas diferenças:

1. A função utilizada para a reformatação do gráfico é a `gather()` do pacote **tidyr**. Observe que chamei de **UF** a coluna com os estados e, da forma que o gráfico foi montado, este vai ser o nome da legenda.
2. Inclui a função `scale_fill_manual()`, nela você pode customizar a cor das barras.
3. As labels foram incluídas através da função `labs()`. Por que? Caso você deseje alterar o nome da legenda dos estados, basta incluir o atributo `fill = "Nome da Legenda"`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

Total_CPIs <- data.frame(Período =c(1995, 1999, 2003, 2007, 2011), 
                         SP = c(12, 11, 2, 20, 22), RS = c(3, 4, 2, 4, 4))

df <- gather(Total_CPIs, "UF", "Valor", -Período)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Período), y = Valor, fill = UF)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "CPIs")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo, em `scale_fill_manual()`, você pode alterar as cores das barras e em `labs()`, através do atributo `fill`, é possível alterar o nome da legenda. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Período), y = Valor, fill = UF)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "lightblue")) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "CPIs", fill = "Nome da Legenda")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado.